# CSS total width between divs causes wrap

Tags: html, css

I have an incredibly simple example that doesn't function correctly in both chrome and firefox. Together they should occupy 100% of the width of the parent, but apparently i need to be 5 less pixels than the total width to stop it from wrapping. So the question is why does this wrap and how can I make it not wrap and occupy the total width.

html

```
<body>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</body
```

style

```
html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}

.two {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gy9akf6n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline` or `inline-block` elements preserve white space between the elements (like a `span` or any other inline element). So your total width is 20% + a space + 80%, which is > 100%. The easiest way to fix that is to remove the space between the elements.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="one"></div><div class="two"></div>
</body>
```

Another way is to set `font-size: 0;` on the parent (so the space won't take up any space), then reset the `font-size` in the `inline` elements.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.one,.two {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="one">text</div>
    <div class="two">text</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `float: left;` to both `.one` and `.two`, and then they will be on the same line!

Answer (score 0):

you should know that 'div display as a block in Html ' so if used the div it will take the 100% even if you don't use 100% of the width.
you can solve your problem by using float:

```
.one,.two{
 float:left}
```

to remove float effect you should use add a new div after the two divs

```
<div class='claerFloat'></div>
.claerFloat{clear: left;}
```